# From the book "Bishop- Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" Page 31

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition

[image]

From the book "Bishop- Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" Page 31. Can you help me derive the equation (1.68) from equations (1.69), (1.70) and (1.71).

Please explain every step for the solution if possible.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] to clarify.